# How to get every array value, but with the limitation that I am using it inside while and if loop using php?

Tags: php, arrays, function

I got

```
Array ( [0] => Küche & Haushalt [1] => Möbel & Wohnaccessoires [2] => Wohnaccessoires & Deko [3] => Kerzen & Kerzenhalter [4] => Kerzen [5] => Spitzkerzen ) 
Array ( [5] => Stumpenkerzen ) 
Array ( [5] => Teelichter ) 
Array ( [5] => Windlichter ) 
Array ( [4] => Kerzenhalter [5] => Kerzenständer ) 
Array ( [4] => Kerzenzubehör [5] => Kerzenlöscher ) 
Array ( [5] => Zubehör Sets ) 
Array ( [0] => Accessories ) 
Array ( [0] => Accessories [1] => Dekosand ) 
Array ( [1] => Kerzenlöscher ) 
Array ( [1] => Kerzenzangen ) 
Array ( [0] => Combined ) 
Array ( [0] => Default ) 
Array ( [0] => Kerzen ) 
Array ( [0] => Kerzen [1] => Rustikalkerzen )
```

From this code:

```
public function export(){
$this->state_csv = false;
$q = "SELECT t.Verkaufskanal,t.Kategoriename, t.id, t.Kategorienummer from file as t";
$run = $this->query($q);
if($run->num_rows > 0) {
    $fn = "csv_" . uniqid() . ".csv";
    $file = fopen("files/" . $fn, "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
    $previous = [];
    while ($row = $run->fetch_array(MYSQLI_NUM)) {
        $current = explode("|", $row[1]);
        $array_diff = array_diff($current, $previous);
        if(isset($array_diff)){
            print_r($array_diff);
            echo "<br/>";
        }
        $previous = $current;
    }
    if ($this->state_csv) {
        echo "Successfull";
    } else {
        echo "Unsuccessfull";
    }
    fclose($file);
} else {
    echo "No data found";
}
```

}

I want to get all the values that I have inside every array (row). For example like a string

```
Küche & Haushalt
Möbel & Wohnaccessoires
Wohnaccessoires & Deko
Kerzen & Kerzenhalter
Kerzen
Spitzkerzen
Stumpenkerzen
Teelichter
Windlichter
Kerzenhalter
Kerzenständer
Kerzenständer
Kerzenlöscher
Zubehör Sets
Accessories
Dekosand
```

etc... 
I don't know how to get just one value from the array values which I got from public function export ? Could I please ask someone to write my function ?

Comment: The last paragraph is not comprehensible in any way. Please rephrase it so others could understand it

Comment: Hey Alex, thanks for the reply. I have cleared it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put $array_diff in $result array, which will have all arrays as shown above, Please find the below code to make all array into one so that you can put as an csv file as outputted above.

```
<?php
//After storing $array_diff in $result will look like below array
$array  = [array ('Küche & Haushalt', 'Möbel & Wohnaccessoires', 'Wohnaccessoires & Deko', 'Kerzen & Kerzenhalter', 'Kerzen', 'Spitzkerzen'), 
array ('Stumpenkerzen'), 
array ( 'Teelichter' ) ,
array ( 'Windlichter') ,
array ( 'Kerzenhalter', 'Kerzenständer' ) ,
array ( 'Kerzenzubehör', 'Kerzenlöscher' ) ,
array ( 'Zubehör Sets' ) ,
array ( 'Accessories' ) ,
array ( 'Accessories', 'Dekosand' ), 
array ( 'Kerzenlöscher' ) ,
array ( 'Kerzenzangen' ) ,
array ( 'Combined' ) ,
array ( 'Default' ) ,
array ( 'Kerzen' ) ,
array ( 'Kerzen', 'Rustikalkerzen' ) ];

$result = array();
foreach ($array as $arr)  {
 $result = array_merge($result, $arr);
}

var_dump('<pre>',$result);
```

The resulted array will be as below.

```
array(24) {
  [0]=>
  string(17) "Küche & Haushalt"
  [1]=>
  string(24) "Möbel & Wohnaccessoires"
  [2]=>
  string(22) "Wohnaccessoires & Deko"
  [3]=>
  string(21) "Kerzen & Kerzenhalter"
  [4]=>
  string(6) "Kerzen"
  [5]=>
  string(11) "Spitzkerzen"
  [6]=>
  string(13) "Stumpenkerzen"
  [7]=>
  string(10) "Teelichter"
  [8]=>
  string(11) "Windlichter"
  [9]=>
  string(12) "Kerzenhalter"
  [10]=>
  string(14) "Kerzenständer"
  [11]=>
  string(14) "Kerzenzubehör"
  [12]=>
  string(14) "Kerzenlöscher"
  [13]=>
  string(13) "Zubehör Sets"
  [14]=>
  string(11) "Accessories"
  [15]=>
  string(11) "Accessories"
  [16]=>
  string(8) "Dekosand"
  [17]=>
  string(14) "Kerzenlöscher"
  [18]=>
  string(12) "Kerzenzangen"
  [19]=>
  string(8) "Combined"
  [20]=>
  string(7) "Default"
  [21]=>
  string(6) "Kerzen"
  [22]=>
  string(6) "Kerzen"
  [23]=>
  string(14) "Rustikalkerzen"
}
```

Comment: Hey Mirza, thanks for reply, but I think this can't help me much. 
Firstly I can't put foreach because I am inside a while loop here.

Comment: you can define the `$result = [];` array before loop and add `$result = array_merge($result, $array_diff);` where you are printing the `$array_diff` will accumulate the result in one array. hope this helps !

Comment: Yes, it helps.. Thanks Mirza.